# Can't debug fragments on android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment

I'm using Android-Studio and since last week I couldn't stop at any break point set to any `fragment`.
If I put a break point in the activity, the debugger breaks as expected.
If the debugger comes to a line like: `MyFragment f = new MyFragment();` or any line with a reference to a fragment, and I press "Step into" the debugge`performs the actions but I still see the debugger stands on the line`MyFragment f = new MyFragment();`

Moreover, I noticed that I get a messages like this in the Debug section:

```
fragment = No such static field: 'fragment'
chgPicBtn = No such instance field: 'chgPicBtn'
```

I don't know if it's related but it was worth mentioning.

I've been looking for similar problem online and found nothing.
Thanks for the help

Edit:
This is a function that calls the activity:

```
public void displayView(int position) {

    String tag = "";
    fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new NewFragmentMain();
            if (chgPicBtn != null)
                chgPicBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tag = "NewFragmentMain";
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = EditProfileFragment.newInstance(!bool);
            tag = "EditProfileFragment";
            if (chgPicBtn != null)
                chgPicBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        ...
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag).commit();
    }
}
```

The constructor of NewFragmentMain is empty.

EDIT:

The problem was due to:

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

in the gradle file.
I turned it to false and everything worked.

Comment: Can you share your code here so that it will be much easier for everyone to find the cause?

Comment: Did you try placing the break point in the fragment constructor? Also try cleaning the project and see if that helps

Comment: I tried to put break points everywhere in the fragments. and also clean the project.